# What should I do if Image.load() return int instead of tuple?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to change pixel values in picture by numbers between -5 to 5 in order to make sure that there is no hidden information to read.

I tried to change pixel values, for that I opened a picture by the same way I saw on stackoverflow:

```
def changepic(filef):
    im = PIL.Image.open(filef)
    
    pixelMap = im.load()
    print pixelMap
    

    img = PIL.Image.new(im.mode, im.size)
    pixelsNew = img.load()

    for i in range(img.size[0]):
        for j in range(img.size[1]):
            r= int(pixelMap[i,j][0])+5
            g= int(pixelMap[i,j][1])-3
            b= int(pixelMap[i,j][2])+2
            pixelMap[i,j] = ((r,g,b))
            pixelsNew[i,j] = pixelMap[i,j]       
    im.close()
    img.save(filef)
    img.close()
```

> r= int(pixelMap[i,j][0])
>
> TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

sometimes pixelMap type is int while it supposed to be tuple.

I tried to search it online, every website wrote that the return type have to be tuple and i could not find a solution.

Why is it happening and how can i fix it?

Comment: Maybe the int is an error code? What is the int?

Comment: int(sometype) convert the sometype to int, it should be int already but I wrote it just to make sure i can add the munbers

Comment: I don't think the issue is with `pixelMap` at all; rather, the value returned by indexing into `pixelMap` happens to be an int rather than an R/G/B tuple.  In other words, the problem is occurring on monochrome images...

Comment: It happens in colorful images too